# Covariance matrix is singular iff $\text{Var}(b'X)=0$.

Tags: probability-theory

> > Let $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)'$ be a random vector with covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Show that $\Sigma$ is singular if and only if there exists a non-zero vevtor $b=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)'\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\text{Var}(b'X)=0$.

**Edit**

I think there are the following equivalences:

$\Sigma$ singular $\Leftrightarrow\text{det}\Sigma=0$ $\Leftrightarrow\exists b=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)'\in\mathbb{R}^n, b\neq 0: \Sigma b=0$ $~~~~~~(*)$

Now to the proof:

"$\Rightarrow$":
Let $\Sigma$ be singular. Due to $(*)$, there is some non-negativ $b=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)'\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\Sigma b=0$. Since $\text{Var}(b'X)=b'\Sigma b$, it follows that $\text{Var}(b'X)=b'\cdot 0=0$.

"$\Leftarrow$": Let $b=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)'\in\mathbb{R}^n$ non-zero such that $\text{Var}(b'X)=0$. Since $\text{Var}(b'X)=b'\Sigma b=0$ and $b'$ is non-zero by assumption, it has to be $\Sigma b=0$. By $(*)$, this implies that $\Sigma$ is singular.

Am I right?

Comment: How did you get the second equality? Something must be wrong, you obtain something stochastic equals something deterministic, at the end.

Comment: @Martingalo Just by linearity of the expectation.

Comment: But you don't have any expectation on the two first terms on the left hand-side.

Comment: @Martingalo I changed my idea of proof not using expectations anymore.

Comment: In any case, apply $Var$ to $b' X$ and use the property that $Var(aZ)=a^2 Var(Z)$ then you have that the sum is equal 0 so at least one row must be a linear combination of the others being thus the rank of the matrix strictly less than $n$.

Comment: This is what I used for the equivalence $\text{det}\Sigma=0\Leftrightarrow \Sigma b=0$ for some non-zero $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$.